# Executing SSIS task from C# application

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server-2005, ssis

I can successfully run the SSIS package from my C# App. Is there a way to run a specific task within the SSIS package from .NET (C#) Application?

Comment: As a last resort you could achieve what Daniel proposes below more dynamically using the DTS APIs.

Comment: What about just accessing Task's properties and change them instead of running it? Is that possible?

Comment: Absolutely. [This](http://learnbycoding.com/2011/07/creating-a-simple-ssis-package-programmatically-using-c/#.Tw42oKVSR9Q) differs slightly from the tutorial I recently read about it but should serve the same purpose.

Comment: You wouldn't even need to modify an existing package like the article does. From a dtexec perspective, provide run-time configurations (via /SET) that enable/disable containers i.e. `/set "\Package\Sequence Container.Properties[Disable]";True`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to access Package's Tasks and set properties to it.

```
var task = (TaskHost)package.Executables["Your Package Name"];

task.Properties["Any Property"].SetValue(task, "Property Value");
```

Thanks for everyone's input anyway.

Answer (score 2):

We did something like this with an ASP.NET Web Forms application a few years back basically by creating a SQL Agent Job with just one step that executed the SSIS package that had been deployed to the server and then invoking it via the Enterprise Library

```
    public bool ExecutePackage(string jobName)
    {
        int result = -1;
        bool success = false;

        try
        {
            // "SsisConnectionString" will be the name of your DB connection string in your config
            Database db = DatabaseFactory.CreateDatabase("SsisConnectionString");  
            using (DbCommand dbCommand = db.GetStoredProcCommand("sp_start_job"))
            {
                db.DiscoverParameters(dbCommand);
                db.SetParameterValue(dbCommand, "job_name", jobName);
                db.SetParameterValue(dbCommand, "job_id", null);
                db.SetParameterValue(dbCommand, "server_name", null);
                db.SetParameterValue(dbCommand, "step_name", null);
                db.ExecuteNonQuery(dbCommand);
                result = Convert.ToInt32(db.GetParameterValue(dbCommand, "RETURN_VALUE"));
            }
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            success = false;
        }

        switch (result)
        {
            case 0:
                success = true;
                break;
            default:
                success = false;
                break;
        }

        return success;
    }
```

And in your config:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="SsisConnectionString"
         connectionString="Data Source=<server>;Initial Catalog=MSDB;User Id=<user>;Password=<pwd>;"
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

Comment: How does this allow him to run just a single task?

Answer (score 2):

I think you can open your package using the API, disable all other tasks and then run the whole package