# How to execute a specific task from ssis package using C#?

Tags: c#, ssis, package, task

I want to know how to execute the package from the second task(not from the first one).

The whole package is running correctly by the simple dts code:

```
string pkgLocation;
        Package pkg;
        Application app;
        DTSExecResult pkgResults;

        pkgLocation = "<packagepath>\CalculatedColumns.dtsx";
        app = new Application();
        pkg = app.LoadPackage(pkgLocation, null);
        pkgResults = pkg.Execute();
```

Which is only helping for full package execution, but doesn't relate to specific task execution.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Executing SSIS task from C# application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8827987/executing-ssis-task-from-c-sharp-application)

Comment: The answer there is not what I'm looking for though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmm, SSIS packages are executed as whole. So, you cannot control weather to start it from 1st, 2nd or 3rd task. **But** - you can dynamically disable the 1st task so it would start from the 2nd. So - set *Disable* property of the 1st task as described in [Executing SSIS task from C# application question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8840055/1010622)

Answer (score 0):

We did this by using Precedence Constraints and a package variable which is passed to the package at Execution Time.

For example, add a variable called `@Step` to your package, and when you execute the package, if you want to start at the second task, skipping the first task, pass the value `2` to the `@Step` variable.

Then in your package start with a dummy script task that doesn't do anything.   Think of it as "Step 0".  In the precedence constraint from Step 0 to Step 1, check the value of `@Step`.   If it isn't 1, then don't go to step 1.

Have another precedence constraint going from Step 0 to Step 2, and do the same thing there, checking `@Step` for the value 2.   And so on for all the possible steps you might want to skip/start with.   If there are a lot, it can get very messy, but that's the price you pay for wanting that kind of control over your package execution.